# Как указать путь к svg иконке во vue.js, если svg подключается через object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

Хочу вставить svg картинку на свой сайт, для этого использую тег `<object>`:

```
<object data="@/assets/images/icons/heart.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Вместо иконки внутри этого `object` отрисовывается новый документ. Скорее всего это связано с тем, что webpack и плагины которые используются при сборке не понимают, что путь может быть указан так же в атрибуте `data` и игнорируют этот путь. А далее от браузера идёт запрос по пути `@/assets/images/icons/heart.svg` Сервер не находит никаких совпадений и возвращает новый документ, который вставляется в тег `object` Как быть в таком случае?

Думаю переместить все иконки в папку `public`, чтобы можно было запрашивать их, но мне кажется это какой-то костыль, может быть есть способы лучше?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему с помощью `require()`:

```
<object :data="require('@/assets/images/icons/heart.svg')" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```